# Jetpack Compose - passing data between viewmodels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question about viewmodels and passing data between them. I'm trying to make simple weather app which has two screens(current weather and forecast). In first screen (current weather) I call api from viewmodel and get bunch of data. The question is how to pass this data to second viewmodel. Call api one more from second viewmodel when I have already had the data in first viewmodel, is not good way. What is clearest way how to do that? Save data to Room or DataStore in first viewModel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> **viewModel()** returns an existing **ViewModel** or creates a new one in the given scope. The **ViewModel** is retained as long as the scope is alive. For example, if the composable is used in an activity, **viewModel()** returns the same instance until the activity is finished or the process is killed. For more info refer [this](https://viewModel()%20returns%20an%20existing%20ViewModel%20or%20creates%20a%20new%20one%20in%20the%20given%20scope.%20The%20ViewModel%20is%20retained%20as%20long%20as%20the%20scope%20is%20alive.%20For%20example,%20if%20the%20composable%20is%20used%20in%20an%20activity,%20viewModel()%20returns%20the%20same%20instance%20until%20the%20activity%20is%20finished%20or%20the%20process%20is%20killed.).

So you can using the same viewmodel in both the screens would be an suitable solution for this case.

Edit 1:

Please check this code.

```
class WeatherViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var data = MutableStateFlow<Result<Model>>(Model())
        private set

    fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Make API Call and update data
        }
    } }

@Composable fun MyApp() {
    val visibleScreen by remember { mutableStateOf("weather") }

    val weatherViewModel: WeatherViewModel = viewModel()

    val data = weatherViewModel.data..asStateFlow().collectAsState()

    if (visibleScreen == "weather") {
        WeatherScreen(data) {
            weatherViewModel.fetchData()
        }
    } else {
        ForecastScreen(data) {
            weatherViewModel.fetchData()
        }
    } }

@Composable fun WeatherScreen(weatherData: Result<Model>, refreshData: () -> Unit) {

}

@Composable fun ForecastScreen(weatherData: Result<Model>, refreshData: () -> Unit) {

}
```

Comment: This is my current solution, I have one Share viewmodel. But I received feedback that this is not the best way and I should have viewmodel for every screens.

Comment: @TheKubass Kindly check **Edit 1**.